# Cannot set property 'nUserId' of undefined error in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to call one ReST API when my form checkbox is toggling. When I calling method to call api , I am getting the error like

```
Cannot set property 'nUserId' of undefined at
```

My html file contains the following code,

```html
<div>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="getUserPermisionsByUsernameSearch()">
    Search</button>
</div>
<br /> <br><br />
<div *ngIf="userPermissionObj">
  <div><label for="pl">Permission Level:</label> {{userPermissionObj.sPermLevel}} </div>
  <label for="pm">Permissions:</label>
  <div *ngFor="let pt of permissionType">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" [value]="pt.id" [checked]="userPermissionObj.sPermissionType == pt.name ? true : false"
        (change)="updateUserPermisionsByUsername(userPermissionObj,pt)" />
      {{pt.name}} -- {{userPermissionObj.nUserId}}
    </label>
```

And my ts file contains the following code,

```js
export class ModifyuserpermissionsComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedUser: string;
    selectedInstitution: string;
    filtertext: string;
    public status: boolean = false;
    public data = new Array();

    institutionalUsers: any;
    userNameDetails: any;
    userPermissionObj: any;
    permissionRequestUser: any;
    modificationObj: any;
    userObj: any;
    permision: any;


    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
    displayedColumns = ['UserId', 'PermissionId', 'PermissionLevel', 'PermissionType'];


    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
        public manageuserService: ManageuserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.manageuserService.loadUserListApiMethod()
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.institutionalUsers = data });
    }
    loadUserForSearchPermission(event: any, obj: any) {
        if (event.isUserInput) {
            this.permissionRequestUser = obj.sUsername;
        }
    }

    permissionType = [
        { id: 1, name: 'R' },
        { id: 2, name: 'W' }
    ];

    getUserPermisionsByUsernameSearch() {
        var param: string = this.permissionRequestUser;
        this.manageuserService.getUserPermissionApiMethod(param)
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.userPermissionObj = data });
    }

    updateUserPermisionsByUsername(userObj, permision) {
        this.modificationObj.nUserId = userObj.nUserId;
        this.modificationObj.name = permision.name;
        this.manageuserService.modifyUserPermissionApiMethod(this.userObj)
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.institutionalUsers = data });
    }

}
```

Can anyone guide to find my wrong implementation here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you initialize `modificationObj`?

You are trying to set a property of `undefined` object. It should be looking like below:

```js
updateUserPermisionsByUsername(userObj, permision) {
  // this.modificationObj.nUserId = userObj.nUserId;
  // this.modificationObj.name = permision.name;

  this.modificationObj = {
    nUserId: userObj.nUserId,
    name: permision.name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `userPermissionObj` property is only initialised when you click on the search button.

Answer (score 0):

In  `this.manageuserService.modifyUserPermissionApiMethod()`, you have to pass the value you got as parameter. Instead of calling modifyUserPermissionApiMethod() with param userObj, you used `this.userObj`. Try the same code by removing the `this.`

```
updateUserPermisionsByUsername(userObj, permision) {
            this.modificationObj.nUserId = userObj.nUserId;
            this.modificationObj.name = permision.name;
            this.manageuserService.modifyUserPermissionApiMethod(userObj)
                .subscribe((data: any) => { this.institutionalUsers = data });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set object properties to an `undefined` property. You need to initialize your object first, then you can add or modify properties of it.

There are many ways of doing this but here's two of them.

First:

```
export class ModifyuserpermissionsComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedUser: string;
    selectedInstitution: string;
    filtertext: string;
    public status: boolean = false;
    public data = new Array();

    institutionalUsers: any;
    userNameDetails: any;
    userPermissionObj: any;
    permissionRequestUser: any;
    modificationObj: any = {}; // <-- we have initialized an empty object
    userObj: any;
    permision: any;


    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
    displayedColumns = ['UserId', 'PermissionId', 'PermissionLevel', 'PermissionType'];


    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
        public manageuserService: ManageuserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.manageuserService.loadUserListApiMethod()
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.institutionalUsers = data });
    }
    loadUserForSearchPermission(event: any, obj: any) {
        if (event.isUserInput) {
            this.permissionRequestUser = obj.sUsername;
        }
    }

    permissionType = [
        { id: 1, name: 'R' },
        { id: 2, name: 'W' }
    ];

    getUserPermisionsByUsernameSearch() {
        var param: string = this.permissionRequestUser;
        this.manageuserService.getUserPermissionApiMethod(param)
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.userPermissionObj = data });
    }

    updateUserPermisionsByUsername(userObj, permision) {
        // now you can set properties to modificationObj
        this.modificationObj.nUserId = userObj.nUserId;
        this.modificationObj.name = permision.name;
        this.manageuserService.modifyUserPermissionApiMethod(this.userObj)
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.institutionalUsers = data });
    }

}
```

or the second way

```
export class ModifyuserpermissionsComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedUser: string;
    selectedInstitution: string;
    filtertext: string;
    public status: boolean = false;
    public data = new Array();

    institutionalUsers: any;
    userNameDetails: any;
    userPermissionObj: any;
    permissionRequestUser: any;
    modificationObj: any;
    userObj: any;
    permision: any;


    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
    displayedColumns = ['UserId', 'PermissionId', 'PermissionLevel', 'PermissionType'];


    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
        public manageuserService: ManageuserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.manageuserService.loadUserListApiMethod()
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.institutionalUsers = data });
    }
    loadUserForSearchPermission(event: any, obj: any) {
        if (event.isUserInput) {
            this.permissionRequestUser = obj.sUsername;
        }
    }

    permissionType = [
        { id: 1, name: 'R' },
        { id: 2, name: 'W' }
    ];

    getUserPermisionsByUsernameSearch() {
        var param: string = this.permissionRequestUser;
        this.manageuserService.getUserPermissionApiMethod(param)
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.userPermissionObj = data });
    }

    updateUserPermisionsByUsername(userObj, permision) {
        this.modificationObj = {} // you can initialize your object here
        
        // or maybe
        // this.modificationObj = { 
        //   nUserId: userObj.nUserId,
        //   name: permission.name
        // } 

        this.modificationObj.nUserId = userObj.nUserId;
        this.modificationObj.name = permision.name;
        this.manageuserService.modifyUserPermissionApiMethod(this.userObj)
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this.institutionalUsers = data });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Typescript, try to use Interface model instead of any (`userPermissionObj: any`) as a type.
This will help you reduce these kind of errors

example:

```
interface  UserPermissionObj {
   nUserId: integer,
   name: string
}

userPermissionObj: UserPermissionObj;
```